# "Anti-classical" limit of large Planck's constant

Tags: quantum-mechanics

A central theme in quantum physics is the classical limit where $\hbar \rightarrow 0$, and there is lots of interesting structure to this limit (i.e. classical mechanics).  Is there anything interesting that can be said about the opposite limit $\hbar \rightarrow \infty$?

I considered also a similar statement for relativistic limits, i.e. is there a meaningful  $c\rightarrow 0$ limit, the opposite of the usual non-relativistic limit?  I think the answer in this case is that everything just becomes massless.  (It's a bit subtle because nothing moves faster than $c$, so what is $c$ small compared to?  I think the answer is that it becomes small compared to energetic particles' classical velocity $\sqrt{2E/m}$, which is equivalent to $m\rightarrow 0$, the massless limit.)  If anyone can identify further structure to this limit, I would be interested in that, too.

Comment: If $\hbar\to\infty$, the partition function $Z[J]\to 1$, that is, all you get is the vacuum state and nothing else. If $c\to 0$, everything is massless and there is no matter, only radiation, which is still and doesn't move. Neither of these limits make sense (and FWIW, the opposite naïve limits $\hbar\to 0$, $c\to\infty$ dont make sense either)

Comment: Varying $\hbar$ doesn't do anything for you. You can see this easily in case of the hydrogen atom, which is a well understood, physically very accurate solution. The ground state energy scales with $\hbar^{-2}$, but no matter what numerical value you chose, you simply end up with a hydrogen-like atom, just on a different energy scale. The often-claimed transition to "classical physics" does not occur. If you set it to zero or infinity, you end up with a meaningless equation without time dependence. Time to use every book that does this as a door stop.

Comment: Lots of philosophical and conceptual knots could be avoided if you used proper *dimensionless ratios of dimensionful quantities* in all limits: that is what the classical limit is, ħ/S →0, where S is the action of the problem. Infinite ħ  amounts to actions much smaller than it, which conventional QM does not cover, as it is the unit of all QM processes. Both c and 1/ħ are upper bounds for process quantities, and excluding those leaves little left to study....

Comment: @CosmasZachos: The classical limit isn't that, either. The classical limit comes from weak measurement processes that keep continuously destroying the quantum state. Truthfully, there is no classical limit. The proper non-quantum limit of a free system under constant observation is a random walk. In quantum Zeno we can see that constant observation destroys the decay and the phenomenology of superconductors (and the existence of stable matter and macroscopic magnetism!) teaches us that quantum systems with energy gap are resilient against constant decoherence.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'd love to read a detailed answer by you about these matters. I've seen you post short comments about the classical limit many times: wouldn't it be easier (and more useful) for you to write a longer post some time, and just link to it after that? I feel you've got a lot to say about these topics, and many of us would get to learn from that. Jus sayin'

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform: I agree, we should have an article about it, but I am not the right guy to write it. I can only point out what phenomenology tells us and what is frequently overlooked be many authors (curiously even by Feynman, who I am sure knew better and, if somebody had pressed him, would have written a marvelous synopsis!) and I have a few trivial insights into theory. I am sure that somebody who actually knows how to do the calculations would be a lot better suited to the task than I am.

Comment: @CuriousOne.  "Truthfully, there is no classical limit."? You get the principle of least action in the path integral out of *small* S? Maybe You *should* write your review article!!

Comment: @CosmasZachos: That's an ingenious sleight of hand by Feynman, it looks cool but it's not what happens when a physical system transitions from quantum mechanical to classical behavior. Take a look at quantum experiments that are being done in the lab: they aren't being done by either changing $\hbar$ or by adjusting the action. They are being done by cooling a sample down to cryogenic temperatures, where only one or at most a few quantum mechanical states in the sample are being excited. What happens at high temperature is not that QM goes away, the trees are merely hiding in the forest.

Comment: @CuriousOne:  Let's leave Feynman out of it: the argument is [Dirac's (1933)](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/Dirac33.pdf), p69, 2nd paragraph. You may always suppress decoherence artfully if you contrive, but in a freshman physics lab or the street this does not happened for you automatically,  and Least Action works by statistical de-emphasis of nonextremizing paths. There *are* no Zeno effects in a bowling alley! There is a classical effective world and it works just as Dirac figured out.

Comment: @CosmasZachos: What happens in a freshman physics lab in the basement is exactly the same thing that happens upstairs in the postdoc lab, it's just that the freshmen are (conventionally) being given a bunch of lies to kids about it. The _physical_ transition from QM to CM goes trough TD, whether you like to teach that or not makes no difference to nature. The only difference it makes is to the quality of your teaching. Whether you want to blame Dirac or Feynman for your decision to lie to kids makes no difference to me. I prefer telling them the truth.

Comment: @CuriousOne: but... but... what if I just *gave* the students Dirac's quote with no comment... Is *that* a lie? I've only taught graduate courses, and TA'd one by Feynman, but I'd be delighted to keep mum after I read the anxiously expected review article that yanks me to the Truth... “I'd traded in a pack of lies for a pack of truth, and I didn't know which one was heavier. Which one took the most strength to carry around? It was a ridiculous question, though, because once you know the truth, you can't ever go back and pick up your suitcase of lies. Heavier or not, the truth is yours now.”SK

Comment: @CosmasZachos: If you gave the students nothing but those statements, they would still hear the correct explanation and see the correct calculations with the density matrix in their solid state physics and quantum optics and quantum computing classes and books and they would, eventually, ask themselves why the QM 101 teacher told them such crap.  :-)

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what [our book](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) does.  It juxtaposes decoherence to the *sound* Dirac argument.

Answer (score 6):

First, there's no physical $c\to 0$ limit of relativity because that limit basically says $v\gg c$, velocities are much larger than $c$. But relativity prohibits $v\gt c$, let alone $v\gg c$, so this limit $c\to 0$ i.e. $v\gg c$ cannot be taken. Relativity generalizes non-relativistic physics so that it allows large $v$, $v\sim c$, but at the same moment, it prohibits $v\gt c$, so it prohibits the opposite limit.

The same conclusion actually holds for the hypothetical limit $\hbar\to \infty$ in quantum mechanics, too. The classical $\hbar\to 0$ limit means that one focuses on the regions of the phase space, rectangles $\Delta p \cdot \Delta x$, that are much larger than $\hbar$, the volume of a single quantum cell in the phase space. In that regime, the quantum cells may be approximated by points and the quantum "pixelization" of the phase space may be neglected.

The limit $\hbar \to 0$ would mean that we analyze regions of the phase space whose area or volume is $\Delta x \cdot \Delta p\ll \hbar$, much *smaller* than the Planck's constant, but to study such small regions in the $(x,p)$ space is prohibited by the uncertainty principle. Again, quantum mechanics allows us to overcome the limitations of classical physics (that the angular momenta, actions, and areas of the phase space must be much bigger than $\hbar$) and it allows us to study situations in which they are $\sim \hbar$. But at the same moment, it says that the area in the phase space can't be much smaller than $\hbar$. Also, a nonzero angular momentum can't be smaller let alone much smaller than $\hbar/2$. And the changes of the action $\Delta S$ much smaller than $\hbar$ corresponds to counting the histories involving intermediate states that are not distinguishable, not mutually exclusive.

So both of the "opposite limits" are strictly forbidden by the respective theories, relativity and quantum mechanics.

I may add that the opposite limit is similarly banned for the third major universal constant, Newton's constant $G$. Using the $\hbar=c=1$ units and allowing a variable $G$, $G\sim \ell_{Pl}^2$ in $d=4$. The usual $G\to 0$ limit, i.e. assumption that gravity is weak, is appropriate to study particle physics. However, the opposite $G\to \infty$ limit would mean $\ell_{Pl}\to \infty$ i.e. $L\ll \ell_{Pl}$. Again, this limit is impossible in quantum gravity because one can't study the structure of matter at distances much shorter than the Planck length, basically by the holographic principle, if you wish.

So it's quite a universal fact that there can't exist any "opposite limits" of this kind. In quantum field theory and string theory, we may however study the opposite limits $g\to \infty$ where a coupling constant becomes very large. Here, the conclusion is different. The limit often exists but its physics is equivalent to the same or different theory in the $g\to 0$ due to the S-duality, an equivalence of a theory at coupling $g$ to another (or the same) theory at the coupling $g'=1/g$.

Comment: "Relativity generalizes non-relativistic physics so that it allows large v, v∼c, but at the same moment, it prohibits v>c, so it prohibits the opposite limit."  This is a silly argument based on an arbitrary choice of parameterization.  The opposite limit isn't $v \to \infty$, it's $v\to c$ or, with the rapidity $w =$ arctanh$(v/c)$, it's $w\to \infty$.  This is known as the [ultrarelativisitic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrarelativistic_limit), where many physical quantities simplify.  No idea whether a complete theory can be constructed, but Lubos' simple argument is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you're saying exactly the same thing as I did, in less comprehensible words. Concerning the kinematics in the flat spacetime, special relativity is the *complete* theory for all speeds.

Comment: Thanks for giving us the translation of "Oops, that's what I should have said" in the Motl language :)

Comment: No, you are misinterpreting what I wrote. I wrote that your text was less comprehensible than mine.